# Pass a Struct from C++ to CLI

Tags: c#, c++, .net

The following struct is passed from C++ to CLI (To be used by a C# project).
It is passing an int and an array of structs:

```
public value struct CallbackInfo
{
public:
    int callbackType;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(System::Runtime::InteropServices::UnmanagedType::ByValArray, ArraySubType = System::Runtime::InteropServices::UnmanagedType::LPStruct, SizeConst=1)] array<SystemInfo>^ SystemInfo;     
};
```

How do I modify this so that it only passes a single copy of the struct SystemInfo? And not an array which is of size 1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it like this:

```
public value struct CallbackInfo
{
public:
    int callbackType;
    SystemInfo systemInfo;     
};
```

Comment: Where is the best place to start learning this language at? For example If I have to pass a variable or any sort, how do I know what to pass it as?

Comment: I don't know of any really good and comprehensive book or web tutorial on interop. I've often wondered whether that's a gap that should be filled.